# WebStorm + ESLint auto-fix false positive errors on recompile

Tags: reactjs, eslint, webstorm

I have a pretty annoying problem with ESLint in WebStorm.

If I make changes to a .js file while leaving lint errors that can be automatically fixed by the lint fix, and then press <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> to save the file, the project compilation and lint auto-fix start simultaneously. The auto-fix always corrects the errors in the file, but often the compilation runs before the auto-fix, resulting in false-positive errors in the console after compilation, which were already fixed during the process.

ESLint was configured based on the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/eslint.html).
There is no other formatter or linter triggered on save. The used ESLint version is 8.35.0. Does anyone have any ideas on what could be the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: I've submitted a ticket to jetbrains as well https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-62979/WebStorm-ESLint-auto-fix-false-positive-errors-on-recompile